# Apache Storm SleepSpoutWaitStrategy Behaviour

Tags: apache-storm

I am running an Apache Storm [benchmark](https://github.com/intel-hadoop/storm-benchmark) on a local machine. 
However, I am seeing a weird behavior. One of the benchmarks i.e., SOL (Speed of light) test, uses a `RandomMessageSpout` to generate random tuples as source. Here is the `nextTuple()` code for that spout:

```java
public void nextTuple() {
    final String message = messages[rand.nextInt(messages.length)];
    if(ackEnabled) {
        collector.emit(new Values(message), messageCount);
        messageCount++;
    } else {
        collector.emit(new Values(message));
    }
}
```

When I run this benchmark and profile it using a Java profiler (Yourkit in my case). The spout thread shows sleep intervals in accordance with the `SleepSpoutWaitStrategy.emptyEmit()`. As my understanding goes, this function is called when `nextTuple()` has no tuples to emit and thus the spout thread goes to sleep for a configurable amount of time, as shown in the screenshot. [image]

I do not understand why this function would be called given this particular `nextTuple()` implementation that will always return a tuple. What I am misunderstanding here?

Comment: Your understanding about waiting strategy is absolutely correct. Have no clue why the method is called...

Comment: What application is the screenshot from?

Answer (score 2):

Empty emit is also called in following situations

- If the number of unacked messages reach the max spout pending.
- If the executor send queue as well as the overflow buffer of spout is full.

Comment: Interesting. Let me check, I think the first one might be the reason behind this behaviour.